# Redis: is using private IP faster than public IP?

Tags: redis, connection

Say 2 computers are in the same network. Computer A wants to connect to the Redis residing on Computer B. Is it better to specify computer B's private IP rather than its public IP? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same internal network machines, a private IP is better since the two machines can communicate bypassing any latency of being public, but a lot of people are seeing the opposite since now it is not physical machines that you are dealing with, and virtualised boxes are heavily protected with firewalls even in a private network.

Check as an example what Redis Labs say about AWS :  https://redislabs.com/blog/go-public-or-stay-private-which-aws-network-address-should-paas-users-use